# Encapsulate test method

Tags: spock

Is it possible to encapsulate a test method to reuse it?

I could describe what I want to achieve as

```
// generic test method
def genericMethod(args){
  given:
     def request = args.request
  when:
     def response = http.post(request)
  then:
     response.data == args.responseData
}

def specificTest1(){
  genericMethod([request: 1, responseData: 2])
}

def specificTest2(){
  genericMethod([request: 'A', responseData: 'B'])
}
```

Unfortunately, Spock doesn't seem to work this way.

I am aware of `expect:` and `where:` labels but they are not suitable for my case.

Is it possible to simulate what I designated in the code above?

**Partial Success**

I could partially succeed when using `expect:` only.

```
// generic test method
def genericMethod(args){
  def request = args.request
  def response = http.post(request)

  response.data == args.responseData
}

def specificTest1(){
  expect: 
     genericMethod([request: 1, responseData: 2])
}
```

The test run but `specificTest1()` tests only whether `genericMethod` is T of F. (Yes, it's obvious. :-) )

Comment: You can't encapsulate a test method in spock.
There are a lot of ways to handle this. I think the best way is to use the `where` block. The other way to encapsulate a test method is to have a abstract base spec with this base method. You need to provide setters/getters.
You then create new Specs that inherit from the base and use the setters to encapsulate.

Comment: @Royg, man, can you please outline the proposed solution with the abstract base spec? Maybe a trait would be more suitable? Btw., I said `where` blocks are not suitable. That's -1 point. No, just kidding. ;-) +1 For the idea with the abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this was also raised as an [issue #724](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/724), I'll post the answer here as well:

You need to explicitly add assert before your comparison. Implicit assertions are only applied in special block such as the then: block.

So `response.data == args.responseData` would get it to work.